# Why this structural type bound does not work as expected?

Tags: scala, structural-typing

I'm trying to write a simple helper method that receives something that can be closed and some function which receives the former and ensures the "closeable" is closed after executing the function.

For example, I want to use it like this:

```
  closing(new FileOutputStream("/asda"))(_.write("asas"))
```

My impl is

```
object Helpers {

  def closing[T <: { def close }](closeable: T)(action: T => Unit): Unit =
    try action apply closeable finally closeable close

}
```

But when trying to compile this simple test:

```
object Test {

  import Helpers._

  closing(new FileOutputStream("/asda"))(_.write("asas"))

}
```

The compiler complains with:

> inferred type arguments
>   [java.io.FileOutputStream] do not
>   conform to method closing's type
>   parameter bounds [T <: AnyRef{def
>   close: Unit}]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to write

```
def closing[T <: { def close() }]
```

there is a difference in Scala between methods with empty parentheses and methods without parentheses at all.

Comment: And `FileOutputStream.write` apparently cannot take a String.  Call `getBytes()` on the String.

Answer (score 7):

Type bounds are tricky.  In particular, Scala keeps track of the number of parameter lists in addition to the parameters themselves.  Try these out!

```
class A { def f = 5 }
class B { def f() = 5 }
class C { def f()() = 5 }
def useA[X <: { def f: Int }](x: X) = x.f
def useB[X <: { def f(): Int }](x: X) = x.f
def useC[X <: { def f()(): Int}](x: X) = x.f

useA(new A)  // This works, but what other combinations do?
```

In your case, you want

```
def closing[T <: { def close() }] ...
```

P.S. If you really plan on using this a lot, you probably ought also play with

```
class D extends B { override def f = 6 }
class E extends A { override def f() = 6 }
```

and see which `use` you need to use in each case.